# order of functions in opengl

Tags: opengl, glut

can somebody explain please, what exactly glutMainLoop does? and is the order of the functions in main important or not?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
      glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
      glutCreateWindow("First Game");

      glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
      glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
      glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

      glutMainLoop();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I come from DirectX land but... When OpenGL creates the window, it has to tell hardware what display mode it wants, so that has to be defined before you create the window.  You can move around Reshape and Display to wherever you want, as long as it's before rendering time.  
  
I'm assuming glutMainLoop will render the scene? [haven't worked with OpenGL before] ... If so, then that must be after clearing of the screen and zbuffer, and the window has been created and such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly accenting ItzWarty's comment:  [glutMainLoop](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html)

Essentially it's how your GLUT application is able to process events.

Answer (score 0):

glutMainLoop has been explained
Yes order matters, but its nothing great. Very logical

First you initialize display mode
Next u set the properties of the window,size position\
Now you create a window

Now comes the main part, you register all your callbacks i.e display fn etc
THats it! Now you call your event processor!